# SQL paging query with linked table and ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle11g, db2

I want to share some SQL queries that I use for paging when a joined table and ordering is needed.
In these examples, the result set is limited to row numbers 2-3.

### MySql 5.1:

```
SELECT outerO.Id, outerO.Value 
FROM MyTable outerO 
WHERE outerO.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT o.id FROM MyTable o  
  JOIN LinkTable l ON l.Fk = o.Id 
  WHERE o.Value LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'
) 
ORDER BY outerO.Value DESC, outerO.Id ASC 
LIMIT 2 
OFFSET 1
```

This one shows best what I want to achieve. Oracle 11 and DB2 are much more complicated.

### Oracle 11:

```
SELECT outerO.Id, outerO.Value 
FROM MyTable outerO 
WHERE outerO.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM( 
    SELECT row_.id, rownum rownum_ 
    FROM (
      SELECT id 
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT o.Value, o.Id 
        FROM MyTable o  
        JOIN LinkTable l ON l.Fk = o.Id 
        WHERE o.Value LIKE ? ESCAPE '!' 
        ORDER BY o.Value DESC, o.Id ASC
      )
    ) row_ WHERE rownum <= 3
  ) WHERE rownum_ > 1
) 
ORDER BY outerO.Value DESC, outerO.Id ASC
```

I found no way to do this with fewer subselects.

### DB2 10.5:

```
SELECT outerO.Id, outerO.Value 
FROM MyTable outerO 
WHERE outerO.id IN (
  SELECT inner1_.id 
  FROM (
    SELECT inner2_.id, rownumber() 
    OVER(ORDER BY ORDER OF inner2_) AS rownumber_ 
    FROM (
      SELECT id 
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT o.Value, o.Id 
        FROM MyTable o  
        JOIN LinkTable l ON l.Fk = o.Id 
        WHERE o.Value LIKE ? ESCAPE '!' 
        ORDER BY o.Value DESC, o.Id ASC
      ) 
      FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS inner2_
  ) AS inner1_ 
  WHERE inner1_.rownumber_ > 1 ORDER BY inner1_.rownumber_
) 
ORDER BY outerO.Value DESC, outerO.Id ASC
```

I found no way to do this with fewer subselects.

### Microsoft SQL-Server 2016:

```
SELECT outerO.Id, outerO.Value 
FROM MyTable outerO 
WHERE outerO.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT o.id 
  FROM MyTable o  
  JOIN LinkTable l ON l.Fk = o.Id 
  WHERE o.Value LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'
) 
ORDER BY outerO.Value DESC, outerO.Id ASC 
OFFSET 1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

---

**These queries do work for me, but perhaps there are better solutions available?**

Comment: Exact duplicate (as the OP posted it twice) of [SQL select for update with linked table and ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391748/sql-select-for-update-with-linked-table-and-ordering)

Comment: No, it's no duplicate. They only look very similar!

Comment: You might want to actually make them look different then. The queries are almost identical (The MySQL one looks like you've only replaced `FOR UPDATE` with `LIMIT 2 
OFFSET 1`, so they are effectively the same. SQL Server, the same, apart from you dropped the usage of `NOLOCK` too (likely the correct choice)), there's little explanation to go with the topics, and they basically have the same title.

Comment: This question shows the different syntaxes for the handling of rownum, my other question shows the different syntaxes for the handling of ´for update´ (especially with the SQL-Server).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in DB2

```
SELECT ID, VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT ID, VALUE, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.Value DESC, o.Id ASC) AS RN
  FROM MyTable
  JOIN LinkTable l ON l.Fk = o.Id 
  WHERE o.Value LIKE ? ESCAPE '!' 
  ORDER BY o.Value DESC, o.Id ASC
) X
WHERE RN > 1 AND RN <= 3
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't have a linked table in your where clause, everything is much easier. In my example I linked the table LinkTable.

Comment: @tangens -- sorry I missed part of the query -- I've updated it to include the join and sorting -- I don't think that the syntax is right for DB2 but I left it as is.